# Build and export PDF maps using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, cartography

I have a series of featureclasses and rasters generated using ArcObjects and calls to the Geoprocessor. I have the paths to the output, which are located in a file geodatabase. How can I use ArcObjects to build a map using a combination of these outputs and then save the final map as a PDF (or JPEG/PNG if PDF is not possible)? If this is possible, can I also add a legend/north arrow, etc?

The purpose of these maps is quick quality control and the output are all in the same projection and cover the same area.

I'm unfamiliar with building visual outputs "behind the scenes" in ArcObjects, so any information that points me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Just about everything you can do in ArcMap you can do in ArcObjects, it's more a matter of how much coding you want to do! This isn't a real answer, just some pointers: You'll probably want to use layer files to define the symbology beforehand, because defining symbology programmatically can take many many lines of code. Better yet is to design template MXDs that you then only have to modify slightly programmatically, something you might want to consider using [arcpy.mapping](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/00s3/00s300000032000000.htm) instead for.

Comment: Additionally you might see if using [Data Driven Pages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000006000000) could suit your purposes to avoid programming entirely.

Comment: Starting with layer files is a great idea - I'm going to try and stick to .NET as much as possible for this run since the software we've developed is all C# up to this point. If I have to I'll create a separate process for using arcpy that can be run after the output is produced.

Comment: Speaking from experience, it is MUCH quicker and easier to use arcpy for doing this.  If you are not opposed to it, you may consider creating a python script that does this stuff, and call the script from your c# sharp code.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I think calling the python script from C# is what I'll do. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the programming route to export using ArcObjects you can use the Export active view code sample, see link below.  I would suggest to pre define layouts objects such as north arrow and scale bar manually.

[Export active view](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000026000000)

Comment: I agree, use the new PrintAndExport API, see also the IExportPDF: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Exporting_maps/0001000001z1000000/

Answer (score 2):

Hy,
I did a ServerObjectExtension containing advanced print functionalities.
I did it in Java, but the code is very close to .NET
May be a good inspiration of the ArcObject code.

The open-source code can be found here:
 http://bitbucket.schuller.lu/pchprintsoe/src/3d532e06e658/src/lu/etat/pch/gis/soe/tasks/print/PrintTask.java

Tom